# httpClient.GetAsync call throw System.ArgumentException: Could not determine JSON object type

Tags: c#, json, linq

I try to call a get api by httpClient.GetAsync. But I get exception

> "System.ArgumentException: Could not determine JSON object type for
>   type System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject].\r\n 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.GetValueType(Nullable`1 current, Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.CreateFromContent(Object content)\r\n 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
>   content, Boolean skipParentCheck)\r\n   at
>   MediaIngestionSFSvc.Controllers.MediaIngestionController.d__2.MoveNext()"

Here is the api I try to call

```
public IActionResult GetSKUByEditionDisplayName(string edition)
    {
        string message = null;
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(edition))
            {
                message = $"Edition is null";
                throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
            }

            SqlQuerySpec sqlQuery = repository.GenerateQuery(CollectionName, new KeyValuePair<string, object>(Enums.id.ToString(), MediaRefreshConstants.SKUtoEditionTable));
            IEnumerable<JObject> docs = repository.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(sqlQuery);

            if (!docs.Any())
            {
                message = $"No SKUtoEditionTable found in Cosmos db";
                throw new NullReferenceException(message);
            }

            string responseBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docs);
            string jsonObject = responseBody.Trim().Trim('[', ']');
            JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(jsonObject);

            if (responseObject[edition] == null)
            {
                message = $"No Edition {edition} found in SKUtoEditionTable";
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }

            string sku = responseObject[edition].ToString();
            return CreateActionResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, sku);

        } catch (Exception e) when (e is ArgumentNullException || e is NullReferenceException)
        {
            message = $"Fail to retrieve sku from EditionToSKUTypeMapping table";
            return CreateActionResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.ToString());
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = $"Fail to retrieve sku from EditionToSKUTypeMapping table";
            return CreateActionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Do not know what happen, can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error you are receiving is because you do not `await` the `repository.ReadItemAsync<JObject>` call. So the return type is `Task<JObject>`, not `JObject`.

Change

```
IEnumerable<JObject> docs = repository.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(sqlQuery);
```

to

```
IEnumerable<JObject> docs = await repository.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(sqlQuery);
```

That being said, there are some additional things that could be causing problem. If you are serializing an array object, then trimming away the `[` and `]`, it is no longer valid JSON if there is more than one element in the original array. Also, serializing an object to JSON to immediately deserialize it is a bit odd and might warrant some rethinking.

Comment: even the method is readItemAsync, it is not a async method. And what I return at last is not the doc. I return a sku string.

Comment: If it isn't an async method, then it should not be named as so. This is very poor form for readability and usability.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by this way:
This is the original logic:
                public async Task A(string uri, string contentType)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            return httpResponseMessage;
        }

```
   private async Task<string> B(string edition)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage keyValueResponse = await new HttpHelper().A(keyPairUrl, JsonContentTypeHeaderValue);
        string responseBody = await keyValueResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBody.Trim();
    }

  private async<JObject> C() {
   JObject object = new JObject();
object["s"] = await B(some string);
return object;
}
```

it will throw above exception:
But if I change the await B(somestring); to B(somestring).Result;
The issue will be gone.

I am pretty for c#, can someone tell me why it happen? Is there anyother better way to solve it.